# Spelling errors in commit and what to do if "ahead by 1 commit"

Tags: git

I committed something and realize my comment had a spelling error, so I typed `git commit -m "xxx"` again, with corrected comment.

As a result, I can't push anything as git push says

```
Everything up-to-date

# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. 
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git rebase -i origin/master` will give you the opportunity to correct the commits you have beyond your upstream repository. Then you can `git push` the result.

Answer (score 5):

As [Novelcrat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90002/novelocrat) points out, you can rebase interactively to fix up commits before pushing. In the future if you make a mistake in a commit message you can edit it with `git commit --amend`